# Saving html canvas background image with canvas drawing included

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is it possible that after user finished their drawings and save both backgroundImage and drawings that they did?

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // comes from html
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get context of canvas

 canvas.style.backgroundImage = `url(${value.result.questionImage})`; // images comes from sql database.

 // user does some drawing on the canvas...
```

Comment: Did you try canvas.toDataURL() ?

Comment: yes, canvas.toDataURL() just get the drawings that the user did on the canvas. Somehow, I need to combine both canvas.style.backgroundImage + drawings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw the background image on the canvas instead of using style:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // comes from html
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // get context of canvas

 var image = document.createElement('img')
 image.onload = ()=>context.drawImage(image, 0,0);
 image.src=value.result.questionImage;
```

Now, when the you get the data url the question image will be used also because it is now an ordinary part of the canvas.